# Flutter Nested DragTargets

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, draggable

A DragTarget that responds to a Draggable over it is a common need. What if you want to provide the user with additional options by morphing that widget into multiple DragTargets ?
Giving those options different behaviors is out of scope of a single DragTarget without doing offset math. Below is my best attempt at doing it with multiple, but it doesn't work.

https://dartpad.dev/?id=6372556cac328255f93c5390a3a31220
(Drag + over blue area, observe flicker)

I'd like the widget to change into the two DragTarget, allowing me to drop my Draggable on one.

The multiple DragTargets interfere to cause this flickering effect.

Any suggestions?